# Unable to remove the double quotes from the value pair

Tags: javascript, json, momentjs

I am getting the date data and setting the date into the JSON object

```
let lastSeven = moment().subtract(7, 'd').toDate();
var dat =  moment(lastSeven).format('D');

dat = dat.replace(/^"(.*)"$/, '$1');
```

I have to get the data like this

```
{
  'year': 2018,
  'month': 9,
  'day': 14
};
```

But after the replace also I am getting

```
{
  'year': "2018",
  'month': "9",
  'day': "14"
};
```

How can I remove the double quotes from the values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well with out the double quotes they would be numbers, so convert all value to number.

```js
let obj = {
  'year': 2018,
  'month': 9,
  'day': 14
};

for (let property in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) obj[property] = +obj[property];
}
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need convert string to number.

```
for(var key in data){
    data[key] = Number(data[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this way using `Array.prototype.map()`

```js
var myObject = {
  'year': "2018",
  'month': "9",
  'day': "14"
};
var result = {};
Object.keys(myObject).map(function(key, index) {
  result[key] = +myObject[key];
});
console.log(result)
```